# Entity Framework multiple object relations to same column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, entity-framework

I have couple of entities such as `Customer`, `Vendors`, `Employee` and I have another entity to handle `Transaction Head`, check definition here:

```
public class TransactionHead
{
    public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public DocumentType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public Location From { get; set; }
    public object To { get; set; }//customer, supplier, location, employee "will have a discount table "
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public float GrossAmount { get; set; }
    public float TotalDiscount { get; set; }
    public float NetAmount { get; set; }
    public int DetailRowCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public User Created { get; set; }
    public User Updated { get; set; }
    public User Approved { get; set; }
    public DocumentStatus DocumentStatus { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalRemark { get; set; }
    public string DocumentRemark { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

And now when I create migration, it automatically ignores the `To` property from `TransactionHead` entity. So what is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of **To** property? Why to naming it **To**? Why it is **object** type?

Answer (score 0):

No. EF doesn't support this because it would require `dynamic` column type in the database. the `object` property that EF will always ignore. you can find more information about complex type in EF in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680147(v=vs.113).aspx) link.